# Adding Author Name in document Header using StyleCop

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stylecop

I am using StyleCop with Visual Studio. Whenever i add a new file it adds few information like company name ,copyright details. 
I want to add author name and creation date also .Is it possible to update the StyleCop Setting somewhere to support this ?

Comment: Are you talking about adding a new StyleCop rule to check that the information exists, or using the new templates that come with StyleCop?

Comment: not adding a rule .. 
its like adding a new template so that along with company name etc ,author name and creation date will come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/sharing-source-analysis-settings-across-projects.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/managing-source-analysis-project-settings.aspx

Between them you are sorted ;)

So you create a stylecop settings file for a project (right click on project -> stylecop settings) then copy it into solution root and all the projects will basically inherit their stylecop settings from it.

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 1):

The StyleCop templates are located at `/Common7/IDE/ItemTemplates/CSharp/Code/1033` relative to the Visual Studio install location (VS2010 by default will be either `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0` or `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`, look first in the x86 folder if both exist).

The templates are supplied in zip files containing a `.cs` file and a `.vstemplate` file. Extract the zip file, modify the `.cs` file, re-zip the two files and place it back in the original folder (I recommend creating a backup of the original just in case). In order to have Visual Studio actually use your new, modified template, run this command in a command prompt:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" /setup"
```

You'll notice that the template format is a bit different than a regular C# file. This allows for the ability to customize how the template appears based on different settings. MSDN has several guides on how these work and how to use them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247113.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185311.aspx

Comment: what is name of this template zip file

Comment: and i dont see any devenv.com folder uner IDE

Comment: For just C#, there are 6 separate templates - `Class.zip`, `CodeFile.zip`, `Interface.zip`, `SilverlightClass.zip`, `AdoNetEntityDataModelT4CodeGenCSharp.zip`, and `AdoNetEntityDataModelT4SelfTrackingCodeGenCSharp.zip`. You may have more on your system, those are just the ones that are on mine. There are hundreds of more templates located all throughout the `ItemTemplates` folder.

Comment: You have to run that command from command prompt. devenv.com isn't a folder, it's a COM executable. It runs the first time setup again, which extracts all the templates again and updates the cache.