# Adding author name automatically in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I want to add creator name into when all .cs and .xml files created. So I could use Eclipse as follows, but I cannot use this in Visual Studio

> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code templates

```
/**
 * @author ${user}
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: You can create snippet, that will do that for you.

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139571/adding-author-name-in-document-header-using-stylecop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the template for your classes that can usually be found under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio *version*\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;

/**
* @author $username$
*
* @date - $time$ 
*/

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

The complete list of Template Parameters you can find [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx).

In VS2015 the cs file located in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.cs

Comment: I changed and saved it but still nothing changes. I am also using VS 2015

Comment: Try to change `ItemTemplatesCache` files also, located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache`.

Comment: @BerkayKırmızıoğlu does it help you?

Comment: I've checked it in VS 2015 Enterprise, working correctly.

Comment: That helped me a lot. Thank you