# auto generate comments at the top of the Program.cs file in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, comments, visual-studio-2019, auto-generate

I'm new to Visual Studio 2019 and C#. Is there a way to auto generate comments at the top of the project solution Program.cs file with the file name , author, date stamp, version, etc.,(ideally every time a new project or an individual class file is created)? I've done it in the past in Eclipse and JetBrain's products thru a simple template file but it doesn't appear to be that cut and dry in Visual Studio 2019.

I tried this just to test it:
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication\program.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$

/** 
* $safeprojectname$
* $username$
* $time$
*/

namespace $safeprojectname$
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Duplicated:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195179/adding-author-name-automatically-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be Visual Studio 2015 not 2019 but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Doesn't work and the latter reference to a ItemTemplatesCache doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure what kind of projects did you use, but you need to change the corresponding file of the template. For example, if you use C# Console Application (.NET Framework) project, and want to let the comments show at the top of the `Program.cs` file in VS, then you need to go to this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\[version like Community]\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication` open the program.cs file and change the codes.

Comment: If you change the `Class.cs` file under this path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\\[version like Community]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class`, this will work when you add a new item (`Class.cs` file) to the exist project.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, still no go. Added an edit to my OP to show the test I'm attempting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EditorConfig to [Add file header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/add-file-header?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but does this option only work within an existing project or any time a new project is created?

Comment: @Hamberfim If you add an EditorConfig to a solution, it should work for both new and existing projects.

Comment: Thanks Sergey but it doesn't work for my needs. Can't use multilines nor honor the use of dynamic names like $safeprojectname$